Is 食べようかどうか迷っている grammatical?
I can't find any resource that specifically addresses using ～かどうか after the the volitional, in a sentence like:

食べようかどうか迷っている。

Clearly, かどうか has to come after a yes-no question, so the following is ungrammatical:

（！）何を食べたかどうか覚えていません。

By this logic, 食べようかどうか should theoretically be fine because 食べようか (mostly) looks like any other yes-no question.
But somehow it still feels somewhat borderline to me, and I'm not sure if I've ever heard it. There are a few examples online, but not many.
What I have heard much more commonly would be something like:

食べようかどうしようか迷っている。

Am I just imagining things? Is 食べようかどうか totally normal?

Yes, 食べようかどうか迷っている sounds perfectly natural to me. This どうか is optional.
食べようかどうか means "whether or not I will eat it"; it's a simple comparison between "to eat" and "not to eat". On the other hand, 食べようかどうしようか ("whether to eat it or what to do") may sound like they're considering several options (e.g., 食べる, 捨てる, 持って帰る, 人にあげる, ...).
